# BIRT interpolate data in crosstab for rows/cols without data

Tags: birt, maximo

Crosstab interpolate data so graph 'connects the dots'

I have trouble with my crosstab or graph not interpolating the data correctly. I think this can be solved, but I'm not sure. Let me explain what I did.

I have a datacube with the rows grouping data by weeknumber and the cols grouping data per recordtype. I added to flagbits to the dataset so I can see if a record is new or old. In the datacube I added a measure to sum these bits per row/col group. Thus effectively counting new and old records per week per coltype. I also added a sum of records per coltype.

In the crosstab I added two runningsums for the new and old records sums. In the crosstab I added a datacell to calculate the actual records per row/colgroup. Thus actual records = totalcoltype - runningsum(old) + runningsum(new)

So lets say there are 20 records in this set for a coltype.

- In week 1: 3 old records, 2 new records. Then the running sum becomes 3 and -2. Actual = 20 - 3 + 2 = 19 (correct)
- In week 2: no data. The runningsums are not visible. Actual = 20 - null + null = 20 (wrong)
- In week 3: no data. The runningsums are not visible. Actual = 20 - null + null = 20 (wrong)
- In week 4: 2 old records, 1 new recored. The runningsums becomes 5 and 3. Actual = 20 - 5 + 3 = 18 (correct)
- In week 5: no data. The runningsums are not visible. Actual = 20 - null + null = 20 (wrong)
- In week 6: 6 old records, 2 new records. The runningsums becomes 11 and 5. Actual = 20 - 11 + 5 = 14 (correct)
- In week 7: no data. The runningsums are not visible. Actual = 20 - null + null = 20 (wrong)

So the graph will display:

1. 19
2. 20
3. 20
4. 18
5. 20
6. 14
7. 20

If I add a condition to the actual calculation, it becomes:

1. 19
2. null
3. null
4. 18
5. null
6. 14
7. null

The graph doesn't ignore the null values, but thinks they are 0. The graph is wrong.

Is there a way to let the graph realy ignore the null values?
Another solution is that the runningsums display the last know value or just add 0 if there is no data. Any idea how to do this?

Obviously, a correct graph would read:

1. 19
2. 19
3. 19
4. 18
5. 18
6. 14
7. 14